# Why does autograd not produce gradient for intermediate variables?

Tags: pytorch, autograd

trying to wrap my head around how gradients are represented and how autograd works:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

x = Variable(torch.Tensor([2]), requires_grad=True)
y = x * x
z = y * y

z.backward()

print(x.grad)
#Variable containing:
#32
#[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

print(y.grad)
#None
```

Why does it not produce a gradient for `y`? If `y.grad = dz/dy`, then shouldn't it at least produce a variable like `y.grad = 2*y`?

Comment: I think that's an interesting question to be posted at https://discuss.pytorch.org/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> **By default, gradients are only retained for leaf variables. non-leaf variables' gradients are not retained to be inspected later. This was
>   done by design, to save memory.**

-soumith chintala

See: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-cant-i-see-grad-of-an-intermediate-variable/94

## Option 1:

Call `y.retain_grad()`

```
x = Variable(torch.Tensor([2]), requires_grad=True)
y = x * x
z = y * y

y.retain_grad()

z.backward()

print(y.grad)
#Variable containing:
# 8
#[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]
```

Source: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-cant-i-see-grad-of-an-intermediate-variable/94/16

## Option 2:

Register a `hook`, which is basically a function called when that gradient is calculated. Then you can save it, assign it, print it, whatever...

```
from __future__ import print_function
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

x = Variable(torch.Tensor([2]), requires_grad=True)
y = x * x
z = y * y

y.register_hook(print) ## this can be anything you need it to be

z.backward()
```

output:

```
Variable containing:  8 [torch.FloatTensor of size 1
```

Source: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-cant-i-see-grad-of-an-intermediate-variable/94/2

Also see: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-cant-i-see-grad-of-an-intermediate-variable/94/7

Comment: Thanks didn't know about the retain_grad() method