# Why doesn't torch.autograd compute the gradient in this case?

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, backpropagation, autograd

Why doesn't torch.autograd compute the gradient in this case?

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([1., 2., ], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([x[0] + x[1], x[1] - x[0], ], requires_grad=True)
z = y[0] + y[1]
z.backward()
x.grad
```

Output is a blank line (None). The same occurs for `x[0].grad`. Why?

PS: In retrospect, I realize the motivation for making `y` a tensor with `requires_grad` was so I could examine its own gradient. I learned that one must use `retain_grad` for that here: [Why does autograd not produce gradient for intermediate variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988168/why-does-autograd-not-produce-gradient-for-intermediate-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `torch.tensor` for `y`, it just uses the values of `x` to initialize the tensor, the gradient chain is lost.

This works:

```
x = torch.tensor([1., 2., ], requires_grad=True)
y = [x[0] + x[1], x[1] - x[0], ]
z = y[0] + y[1]
z.backward()
x.grad
```

The result is `tensor([0., 2.])`

Comment: Thanks. In retrospect, I realize the motivation for making y a tensor with requires_grad was so I could examine its own gradient. I learned that one must use retain_grad for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988168/why-does-autograd-not-produce-gradient-for-intermediate-variables